# Windows batch file reading from file with no data between delimiters

Tags: batch-file, tableau-api

I have a multi-line CSV that looks like this:

```
A/B//D
E//G/H
```

I am trying to use these a,b,c (blank in this case) & d as parameter inputs. The code I have today is skipping C and assign D to the 3rd position.

```
FOR /F " tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/" %%i IN (MYCSV.txt"') DO tabcmd get "MyView.png?Filter1=%%A&Filter2=%%B&Filter3=%%C&Filter4=%%D" -f "Outputfile.png"
```

Output expected:

Mview.png?Filter1=A&Filter2=B&Filter3=&Filter4=D

What I'm getting:
 Mview.png?Filter1=A&Filter2=B&Filter3=D&Filter4=

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour]. If you read `help for` or visit http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html you will recognize that this is normal behaviour, for /f ignores leading delimiters and counts successive delimiters as only one.

Comment: Dbenham made a nice helper batch file for this. https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5702

Comment: if the change of delimters is only to be able to open it properly with Excel, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42291120/2152082) might be interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) combines adjacent delimiters into one for parsing text. You could however read the whole lines, temporarily insert a non-delimiter character for splitting into tokens and remove it later on, like this:

```cmd
rem // Read whole lines:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("MyCSV.txt") do (
    rem // Store current line:
    set "LINE=%%A"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid trouble with `!`:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem /* Prepend `_` to line string and replace every `/` by `/_`, hence every `/`-delimited
    rem    item becomes preceded by `_`, hence no more adjacent delimiters `/` can occur: */
    for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/" %%a in ("_!LINE:/=/_!") do (
        endlocal
        rem // Get items preceded with `_`:
        set "ITEM1=%%a"
        set "ITEM2=%%b"
        set "ITEM3=%%c"
        set "ITEM4=%%d"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Return rebuild line string with delimiters `,` and preceding `_` removed:
        echo(!ITEM1:~1!,!ITEM2:~1!,!ITEM3:~1!,!ITEM4:~1!
    )
    endlocal
)
```

Of course for just replacing the delimiter character, you could simply do this:

```cmd
rem // Read whole lines:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("MyCSV.txt") do (
    rem // Store current line:
    set "LINE=%%A"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid trouble with `!`:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Return new line string with delimiters replaced:
    echo(!ITEM:/=,!
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. This is helpful but isn't getting me what I want. I am looking to get those 4 values separated out so I can use them somewhere else in the process as filters. Is it possible to be able to put those values in variables that I can then use in my filters? My problem is that the 4th filter is getting applied to 3rd as the 3rd is empty string and batch file is ignoring it.

Comment: You're welcome! I edited the first script to get the field values into separate variables; I hope it helps...

Comment: sorry I didn't get to see this earlier as I was travelling out of town. So, I tried your script and it does exactly what I want it to do. BUT! Now it's not recognizing my "Do Statement". Like I am using this Tabcmd to view a link and apply my filters to it, but it fails at the tabcmd piece.Maybe because I am having it do 2 things in the same For block.
tabcmd get "tableauView.png?Filter1=!ITEM1:~1!&Filter2=!ITEM2:~1!&Filter3=!ITEM3:~1!&Filter4=!ITEM4:~1!" 
 -f "\\SavedFile-!ITEM1:~1!,.png"
    )
    endlocal

)

Comment: Perhaps you should include the intended `tabcmd` command line in your question; at the moment I can't follow, sorry...

Comment: yeah i think I didn't ask the question correct. Let me rephrase the question. I'm sorry I got you confused. Thanks for helping out though.

Comment: I still don't get what's the problem now. Could you precede the `tabcmd` command line by `echo` and check if the output is correct?

Comment: If I use your suggested code and insert the tabcmd code in place of the last echo, the code fails with error that tabcmd is not a recognized command. However, I have been running tabcmd in other codes within for loops. Do you think one "Do" clause in a loop can do only 1 action? And in this case it's assigning values to items. Sorry, I am very very basic when it comes to cmd.

Comment: Okay, I don't know what `tabcmd` is, but it cannot be found, so try to specify its full path, e. g., `"C:\some\directory\tabcmd" ...`; I casn tell you this has definitely nothing to do with the `do` clause of the `for` loop...

Comment: okay so your solution worked. I was doing something else wrong for the tabcmd to error out. Thanks a lot for your help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use powershell as a tool from batch which has an `Import-Csv` cmdlet.
It requires a temporary assignment of headers, which can be removed on saving.
The csv on output will have double quoted fileds with your choice of delimiter.

```
powershell -Nop -C "(Import-Csv '.\mycsv.txt' -Delim '/' -Header (1..4))|ConvertTo-Csv -NoType|Select -Skip 1|Set-Content '.\my.csv'"
```

Sample output:

```
> type my.csv
"A","B","","D"
"E","","G","H"
```