# convert text file with comma deliminator to csv

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, wmic

I am trying to retrieve the data from user groups and exporting it into an excel. So i am able to get the users etc into a text file, but converting them to excel has to be manual(open text file in excel, then do the text import wizard and selecting comma as the deliminator). Is there a way to automate the process whereby using a batch file, i can export the data into an excel with the deliminator already specified? 
This is my code for retrieving the user groups(quite an easy code)

```
start wmic /output:C:\Users\John\Desktop\automation\useraccounts.txt useraccount list full /format:csv
END
```

If i tried to export it to useraccounts.csv, all the data will be in the first column only.
[image: single column]

Comment: *Is there a way to automate the process whereby using a batch file* - Yes! There is :). If I post this as an answer to the only question you asked will you accept and upvote??? .... I know, right....  Please read [ask] to understand why we really can't help with this question on SO.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman yes I'll accept and upvote :)
I've tried using `Workbooks.OpenText` but its giving me an "expected statement" error :(
This is the code I'm trying to run `Workbooks.OpenText FileName:="useraccounts.txt", Format:=6, Delimiter:=","`

Comment: I am confused by your question. Excel opens CSV files and uses the comma by default without having to do anything.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the file with a CSV extension to induce it to apply the automation Squashman just pointed to?

Comment: So are you saying that the raw text file does not have any `,`'s in it? And you're asking if there was a way to convert all your `.txt` files to `.csv` but also putting the `,`'s in?

Comment: @Squashman: actually Excel uses `,` or `;` - depending on localization (installed language) - see my answer.

Comment: @Stephan, that is good to know about the localization. I have also played with using `sepchar=;` as the first line of the file and that has worked well.

Comment: @Squashman `sepchar` doesn't work (for MY Excel at least). Afaik, `SEP=` is the only (known) working thing. The good point: it works with (nearly?) every character - be it a tabulator or a `|` or whatever delimiter anyone chooses to use. As long as it's (and nothing else) on the first line.

Comment: @Stephan, you are correct.  Just mixed it up on my end with the variables I use for my automated scripts.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [undocumented trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42291120/2152082) to tell excel, which character to use as delimiter. You can use that:

```
echo SEP=,>"C:\Users\John\Desktop\automation\useraccounts.csv"
wmic /append:"C:\Users\John\Desktop\automation\useraccounts.csv" useraccount list full /format:csv
```

When you open it,  Excel will know (from the first line `SEP=,`) to separate the columns by `,`, independent of the default language settings (Some localizations use `,` as default delimiter, others use `;`). `WMIC` uses `,` as column delimiter, but apparently your Excel expects `;` instead.

Note: the line `SEP=,` is part of the *file*, but will NOT be part of the *spreadsheet*. So it is lost, when you save the file from Excel.