# Convert a list of files from the folder ... convert comma delimited to pipe delimited

Tags: windows, batch-file

I was writing a windows batch script to convert pipe delimited file to comma delimited. When i run it for a single file it does the conversion but when I am running it for the files in a folder it does not.

I have the code written for single file but it does not loop thru the folder..

```
@echo off

set "INPUT=%C:\temp\source\*.csv"
set "OUTPUT=%C:\temp\dest\"

setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion



> "%OUTPUT%" (
for %%F in (%*) do
(
    delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%INPUT%") do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!LINE:^|^=,!
        endlocal
    )
)
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

i want to run the script on all the files in the folder

Comment: I would suggest that you fix the code so that it works for one file before extending it to work for multiple files. Also as the files you've got are `.csv`, I'd suggest you use [tag:powershell]'s `import-csv` and `export-csv` for this task instead: `Import-Csv -Path '<Path to original CSV>' -Delimiter '|' | Export-Csv -Path '<Path to new CSV>' -NoTypeInformation`. Even if your files are not true `.csv`'s, _(separated doublequoted strings)_, you could still consider using `powershell.exe`: `(Get-Content -Path '<Path to original CSV>') -Replace '\|',',' | Set-Content -Path '<Path to new CSV>'`.

Comment: let me try that

Comment: forgot to mention.. it works for single file.. i want to it run thru the folder and do the same on all the file in the folder

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42288195/batch-script-quicker-echo-output-to-a-csv-file-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my two [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) based comments, expanded for multiple [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) files:

```bsh
$folderPath = 'C:\temp\source\'
$folderPathDest = 'C:\temp\dest\'
Get-ChildItem $folderPath -Name -Filter *.csv |
ForEach-Object {
    $filePath = $folderPath + $_
    $filePathdest = $folderPathDest + $_
    Import-Csv -Path $filePath -Delimiter '|' |
    Export-Csv -Path $filePathDest –NoTypeInformation
}
```

```bsh
$folderPath = 'C:\temp\source\'
$folderPathDest = 'C:\temp\dest\'
# As the pipe is a special character we need to escape it with a backslash
$stringToReplace = '\|'
$stringToAdd = ','
Get-ChildItem $folderPath -Name -Filter *.csv |
ForEach-Object {
    $filePath = $folderPath + $_
    $filePathdest = $folderPathDest + $_
    (Get-Content -Path $filePath) -Replace $stringToReplace,$stringToAdd |
    Set-Content -Path $filePathdest
}
```

*In the latter, if using [powershell-v3.0](/questions/tagged/powershell-v3.0)+ you can also include the `-Raw` option to `Get-Content`, i.e. `(Get-Content -Path $filePath -Raw)`*